# How to automatically log in to instagram account according to Selenium 4.14 latest version?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium4

This is how to automatically log in to Instagram using the following codes. I'm using `Selenium 4.14` and `Firefox browser`.

`text_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="my-text")` Or `driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="email").send_keys("email")` Or
`email_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email_or_username")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your real question/issue is TBH, as you have not mentioned the issue you are facing. However, am just giving you a selenium-python code to launch browser, open Instagram application and send username and password into respective text boxes. Hope this helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
# Click on Allow all cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Allow all cookies']"))).click()

# Send text to username textbox
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("mic test 123")

# Send text to password textbox
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("mic test 456")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can I add clear() and skip_button command to the code you wrote?